# Why is filter not giving same results as push with for..of iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have extracted an array of objects,  from the following raw data: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Miserlou/c5cd8364bf9b2420bb29/raw/2bf258763cdddd704f8ffd3ea9a3e81d25e2c6f6/cities.json

Suffice to say, the data looks something like this:

[0 … 99]
0
:
city
:
"New York"
growth_from_2000_to_2013
:
"4.8%"
latitude
:
40.7127837
longitude
:
-74.0059413
population
:
"8405837"
rank
:
"1"
state
:
"New York"
**proto**
:
Object
1
:
{city: "Los Angeles", growth_from_2000_to_2013: "4.8%", latitude: 34.0522342, longitude: -118.2436849, population: "3884307", …}

I've stored this as `const JSON_LOCS`, referenced in the code below.

I'm trying to filter this down looking for cities that include some specific test. I've approached it 2 different ways. One way seems to work, but `Array.prototype.filter()` doesn't.

```
const test = [];
      for (let t of JSON_LOCS) {
        if (t.city.includes('las')) {
          test.push(t);
        }
      }

      const test2 = JSON_LOCS.filter(loc => { // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
        loc.city.includes('las');
      });
      console.log(test); // Yields a couple of results
      console.log(test2); // Always empty! :(
```

Comment: Your `filter()` function needs to return a value. Try `const test2 = JSON.LOCS.filter(loc => loc.city.includes("las"))`;

Comment: Your `filter` condition is between curly braces. You need to `return` the value of the check here even tho you're using an arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line

```
oc.city.includes('las');
```

write this line

```
return oc.city.includes('las');
```

you simply forget the return statement which in this case will return undefined

Answer (score 1):

remove the { }

```
const test2 = JSON_LOCS.filter(loc => { // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
  loc.city.includes('las');
});
```

into

```
const test2 = JSON_LOCS.filter(loc => // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
  loc.city.includes('las'); // When not wrapped into {} it assumes its the return statement
);
```

Comment: Good to know. I like curly braces for clarity, but, yes, need to use `return` Duh! :|